# How to install zpanel 10.1.1 for Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I copy and pste this on console

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh)
```

but not happend anything

Answer (score 3):

**Do NOT** use `curl` for that.

Run:

```
wget URL
```

Check the content of the script before installing and **never - really N E V E R !!!** run a script in the way `bash <(curl -s URL)`.

And thanks to [@markkirby](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby) - the script for 14.04 is [here](https://github.com/zpanel/installers/tree/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS)

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS/ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
```

Check the content of `ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh` and if the code in the script is ok for you (the script needs `sudo` privileges)

```
sudo bash ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
```

or

```
chmod +x ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
sudo ./ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
```

Comment: 10_1_1.sh won't run on 14.04 `Sorry, this installer only supports the installation of ZPanel on Ubuntu 12.04`., just tried it, here is 14.04 version for you answer https://github.com/zpanel/installers/blob/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS/ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh, but I get error running it `Syntax error: newline unexpected` ?.

Comment: @markkirby Can I add this into the answer?

Comment: Yes it is for you, no need for another answer :)

Comment: why you thing bash <(curl -s URL) is a bad idea?

Comment: How to install in ubuntu 16.04? Will 14.04 willl work?

Comment: @EdikMkoyan because you don't know what you'll be running. If the server operator or someone who breaks into the server puts up a malicious file instead of what you're expecting, bad things will happen.